# Number of background calculations in EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

We have a reasonably large and complex spreadsheet which is increasingly slowing down. This is mainly caused by the use of volatile functions such as networkdays, sumifs and countifs. What I am looking to find out is how many calculations/operations are actually carried out on each change of the spreadsheet. For example, if I have a =Today() function in A1 and a =Sum function in C9 and make a change in D10 then I would have one 'background' calculation as =Today() is 're-calculated'.

Comment: I think it's impossible to measure that.

Comment: The only way that I can't think of is to change all your `Excel Functions` into `Volatile` `Custom Functions` and feed a counter when they are activated.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly set calculations to manual before you make any/all changes, and then set calculations to automatic, when you are done making updates.

[image]

https://www.sumproduct.com/thought/volatile-functions-talk-dirty-to-me

Also, you can identify all cells with formulas quite easily.

```
Sub IdentifyFormulaCells()

'Apply yellow highlight to all formula cells.
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Set ws = ActiveSheet
For Each rng In ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
Next rng

End Sub
```

Finally, see this.

https://www.myexcelonline.com/blog/highlight-all-excel-formula-cells/